# Behavior of NSNumber(value:) in Xcode compared to Open Source Swift Distribution

Tags: linux, swift, swift3, xcode8, ibm-swift-sandbox

Constructing an `NSNumber` with the value `UInt8.max` yields different results in Xcode 8 than it does with the open source build of Swift 3.0 on Linux.

Xcode 8:

```
print(NSNumber(value: UInt8.max)) // 255 (__NSCFNumber = Int16(255))
```

Swift 3.0 on Linux:

```
print(NSNumber(value: UInt8.max)) // -1
```

[Try it online.](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57c706f2ed042db26b718bc2)

Is this intentional?  I would expect the value to equal 255 on both Swift distributions.

As Martin writes in the comments, this appears to be a bug with the Swift interpreter: [SR-90](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-90)

Comment: Is it this bug https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-90 ?

Comment: @MartinR Good eye, looks like it